# Catch error msg return from intent actionview sorry, this video cannot be played

Tags: android, video

Below is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "video/quicktime");
try { 
     startActivity(intent);         
} 
     catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
}
```

Any idea how to catch the msg without displaying `sorry, this video cannot be played` when I trying to play mov file format and replace to my own sentences for error opening?

Comment: What exactly is it you are having trouble with? You already have a try-catch. I assume the error in quesion is indeed thrown by startActivity, so just display a toast or dialog box in the catch part.

Comment: when the video showing error msg but the catch unable to catch it. That the problem i'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently catching an 'ActivityNotFoundException', so other exceptions won't be catched. You either have to change the ActivityNotFoundException to something more generic (e.g. 'Exception') or add another catch-clause

Solution1:

```
try { 
    startActivity(intent);         
} 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
}
```

Solution2:

```
try { 
    startActivity(intent);         
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
} 
catch (...<insert your particular exception type here>...) {

}
```